# Django Imagefield renaming works only every other time

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I'm attempting to upload a profile picture to a django model which should always be named pic.jpg. Old pictures are deleted using django_cleanup.

This works every other time. I upload an image and it's saved as pic.jpg, then upload a different one and it's saved as pic_{randomchars}.jpg (i.e pic_wCU5xwv.jpg).

```
def rename_pic(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join("api/media/me/", filename)
pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_pic)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Opening the uploaded image
            img = Image.open(self.pic)
            output = BytesIO()

            img = img.convert('RGB')
            # after modifications, save it to the output
            img.save(output, format='JPEG')
            output.seek(0)

            # Set field to modified picture
            self.pic = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "pic.jpg",
                                            'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(output), None)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        print(self.pic.name)       # Always prints pic.jpg
        super(MyData, self).save() # Error happens in this line
        print(self.pic.name)       # Prints api/media/me/pic.jpg and api/media/me/pic_{randomchars}.jpg alternating
```

The error happens somewhere in the `super(MyData, self).save()` line, as the file has the correct name before it's called.

Comment: super(MyData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @ShishirSubedi Still doesn't work